# Azure Devops change default repository of pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have pipeline created in (lets call it) project A but its .yaml definition and all templates are located in project B (B/pipelines). Pipeline has multiple checkouts. The java code which I'm compiling and running pipeline on is located in project A (where pipeline is located).

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: docker
      type: git
      name: B/docker
      trigger: none
    - repository: helm
      type: git
      name: B/helm
      trigger: none
    - repository: backend
      type: git
      name: A/backend
      trigger: none
```

When I manually run pipeline git repository branch/tag which I get to pick is project where .yaml definition of pipeline and its templates is located (project B/pipeline). To pick branch from other repositories (e.g. backend) I have to go to Resources...

Is there a way to swap default git repository so e.g. I can pick backend branches/tags on first screen and then on Resources tab other repositories?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XwfI.png)

If I put .yaml definition of pipeline into project A it works fine, but I want to have pipelines from all projects defined in same Project/repo so I can maintene them easier.